# jQuery on("submit") does not bind to elements loaded with ajax because it is inside another form

Tags: forms, jquery

I have a table of items.

The first column of each row contains a checkbox input as part of a form.
The user can click on these checkboxes and then click submit to do bulk actions such as delete items.

I have setup (using jquery) a situation whereby on clicking the 'Add data' link in a row column, a DIFFERENT form is loaded into a third column in which a user can enter item data.

What i then want to do is use ajax to submit this second form. To do this I am using the following code:

```
$(document).on('submit',".add_form",function(event)
{

    event.preventDefault();

    var serial=$(this).serialize();

    var domain=$('[name=domain]').val();


       $.ajax({
     url:"portfolio/transactions/"+domain+"/",
     type:"post",
     data: {data:serial},
     success: function(dat){
$('#transactions_div').html(dat);
     }
   });




});
```

This however does NOT work, and I believe this is because html does not allow forms within forms. My assumption is that jQuery follows such standards and is getting confused when a second form is loaded into a div which is contained within another set of  tags.

Given this, is what I want to do simply not possible?

THanks

Comment: You probably need to replace the submit button with a regular button, as right now both forms are submitted when the native submit function is triggered on the inner form, also submitting the outer form, which is not prevented etc.

Comment: iirc, HTML5 does allow nested forms, but you have to keep in mind that the submit event of the inner form will probably bubble up to the outer form unless you prevent it.

Comment: Bind the events after adding the new element, and when submitting the inner form from submit button do it like `$("rand-form-id").submit();'` or `$(this).parent().submit();` just some thoughts

Comment: The problem is that the 'submit' event is never detected on the inner form and I assume it is because of the invalid html? h4cky - why bind them after as opposed to using on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('submit', ".add_form", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var serial = $(this).serializeArray();
    var domain = $('[name=domain]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "portfolio/transactions/" + domain + "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: serial,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#transactions_div').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The only change here is seemingly the user of serializeArray.. the problem is that the function is not called at all on submit.. not what is contained within.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form class="add_form">
    <form class="secondForm">
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </form>
    <input name="domain" type="text" />
    <!-- Replace the submit-Button with a normal button -->        
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="send"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', "#send", function () {

    var serial = $(".add_form").serialize();
    var domain = $('[name=domain]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "portfolio/transactions/" + domain + "/",
        type: "post",
        data: serial, // serial instead of {data : serial}
        success: function (dat) {
            $('#transactions_div').html(dat);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but the HTML is invalid. Furthermore having to use click on the submit button instead of submit, simply because the html is invalid seems a little hacky..

Comment: This is only an example HTML code. It's missing some attributes.

Comment: Yes I am aware :) What I mean is that embedding one form inside another is the problem - it is invalid. I.E This doesn't answer the question as to how one can achieve the above output without invalid html..